# Understanding a few of the features of BigQuery BigLake

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

From the following [intro to BQ BigLake](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/biglake-intro), it gives the following picture:

[image]

What exactly do the following three things mean in practice:

1. Fast scans
2. Predicate pushdown
3. Row filter evaluation

I believe **predicate pushdown** is the ability to evaluate the `WHERE` expression directly on the data source, so for example if I was running the following query on a MySQL table:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE country="US"
```

Predicate pushdown would be taking the `country='US'` and evaluating that at the native source, whereas if we didn't have the predicate pushdown (in this made up example), it would involve running `SELECT * FROM table` -- copying all the data over to the processing server -- and then evaluating the predicate there. But if this is correct, how would, for example, predicate pushdown work on a csv file?

Also, what would row filter evaluation be? It seems like predicate pushdown and row filter evaluation would be the same thing, but maybe one of these means something more along the lines of "column filter" -- i.e., only bringing over data from the columns that are needed.

And finally, what are 'fast scans'? I suppose this just means parallelized reading of multiple files, or a file that can be read in parallel (such as a json-newline file). Is the actual reading of the file any different than if I were, for example, to copy over a file with a cli tool such as `$ s3 copy myfile .` ?

Comment: In BigQuery SQL statements are written. However, these are automatically translated to a map/reduce workflow. In the end it looks for the user as a normal SQL was executed. With this technique, huge amount of data can be processed. Because the data of the table is distributed over a network and at each server part the part of the data is processed before sending it to the next step. This is "Predicate pushdown" as the data is processed where it is stored. Fast scans are possible because of the parallisation of the data.

Comment: "Row filter evaluation": There are no indexed needed and there is always a full table scan done. The tables can be partioned by one row. Filtering on that row reduces the amount of read data. This is done before the query is executed and the amount of data to be read is show to the user. Because of the backend technique the full table scans are extrem fast and are cheap. Give it a try. Of course for all the features, there is the need to have your data stored in BigQuery and not let be read each time from your bucket.

Comment: @Samuel when you say "processed on the server", what is the server for a GCS file? Or does it require a server over the network to first download the file and then do whatever is required? In other words, for `This is "Predicate pushdown" as the data is processed where it is stored` -- where is the first step the data is processed for a csv file? Not on the actual GCS device, but a networked/attached-server, correct?

Comment: It is processed on BQ itself. BQ is a serverless tool, but you can check in the query details how the data is processed. You can find here the architecture: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/new-blog-series-bigquery-explained-overview

Answer (score 2):

I will try to address each feature independently.

> row filtering
>
> Also, what would row filter evaluation be? It seems like predicate
> pushdown and row filter evaluation would be the same thing, but maybe
> one of these means something more along the lines of "column filter"
> -- i.e., only bringing over data from the columns that are needed.

BigQuery security model allows to grant access at [row level](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage) based on filter conditions. Row filtering refers to the `BigLake` engine capability to enforce your access control rules at row level at runtime during reading where your defined [policies](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-row-level-security#create-policy) will be applied. This is a useful strategy to avoid data duplication or unnecessary views creation for data governance purposes since you can define multiple rules on a single table depending on your needs

> predicate pushdown
>
> Predicate pushdown would be taking the country='US' and evaluating
> that at the native source, whereas if we didn't have the predicate
> pushdown (in this made up example), it would involve running SELECT *
> FROM table -- copying all the data over to the processing server --
> and then evaluating the predicate there. But if this is correct, how
> would, for example, predicate pushdown work on a csv file?

I am not sure what you mean by applying the predicate (`where` clause or filter) in the source, as far as I know this is not possible, specially in a distributed/cloud environment where storage and compute are usually *decoupled*.

Predicate pushdown refers to the capability of applying the predicate in the BQ vectorized runtime instead of the BigQuery IO storage API or the client, which will  reduce the amount of data to be processed and sent over the network. This is also especially useful when you have complex queries involving joins that would require more computation if the filters are applied after the join operations instead of before.

> fast scans
>
> And finally, what are 'fast scans'? I suppose this just means
> parallelized reading of multiple files, or a file that can be read in
> parallel (such as a json-newline file). Is the actual reading of the
> file any different than if I were, for example, to copy over a file
> with a cli tool such as $ s3 copy myfile . ?

This refers to the fact that data can be consumed through the BigQuery Storage API instead of the "conventional" BigQuery API that returns responses in a paginated fashion. More detail can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage). The advantage is, as you mention, it will read the source data in parallel (which will always do from distributed storage systems) but also you will be able to process the data in a more efficient way (distributed/parallel) depending on how you consume it, e.g. DataFlow, Apache Spark, TensorFlow.